# Call Directive Function on click of input tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to call directive function on click of input tag.

Suppose this directive

```
app.directive("autosuggest", function($rootScope,$modal)                           
  {
  return {
        scope: {
          doneFlag      : "=",
          groupFlag     : "="

        },
        templateUrl : "title.html",
        restrict : 'EAC',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
                   scope.init=function(){
                     //funct();   some function
                    }

                }
    };
 });
```

and This is HTML code

```
<input type="text" >
<div autosuggest="" done-Flag="1" group-Flag="1" ></div>
```

when user click on input tag, init Function will be call. so how i will achieved this in angularJs.
Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Can you just bind a click event to the input in link function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a function in the input's scope:

```
<input type="text" ng-click="callFunction()" >
```

but from your example, any function that's in the autocomplete directive will not be in the same scope as the input. I would suggest including the input in the directive template.